# how to properly handle request parameters in a Spring Data REST controller?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

in my Spring Data REST app, I have the following controller:

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/people")
    public class PersonController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<String> savePerson(@RequestBody Person person, UriComponentsBuilder b, @RequestParam Map<String, ?> id) {


            UriComponents uriComponents = 
                    b.path("/people/{id}").buildAndExpand(id);
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
               responseHeaders.setLocation(uriComponents.toUri());
               responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World\n\n", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    }
```

When I make the following post:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:8080/people
```

I get this error:

```
{"timestamp":1476418616900,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Map has no value for 'id'","path":"/people"}
```

What should I change to fix this error?

Comment: you are correct. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you haven't pass `id` , this URL should be `localhost:8080/people/123`

**note** - 123 is `id`

Answer (score 0):

As @Parth Solanki mentioned localhost:8080/people/123 will solve this issue. But this is not RESTful enough. Since it's a post, I would encourage you to change the URL mapping in the controller method and parameter so that it will remove ID from the URL. 
Or rather keep the same code and change the method to PUT instead of POST. I wouldn't do the latter. Because it needs the consumer to know the id of the resource upfront and its a create rather than an update of the entity that already exists.